# Selenium undetected chromedriver with different chrome-versions?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have the following code which works fine on a computer where chrome 122 is installed currently -

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://ballzy.eu/en/men/sport/shoes')
```

But when I run this code on a computer where a different chrome-version is installed like 120, I get the following error -

```
(selenium) C:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\stefamn_jan669_jankore_janxx2\Ballzy>python test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\stefamn_jan669_jankore_janxx2\Ballzy\test3.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=122)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 466, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 724, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:50596
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 122
Current browser version is 120.0.6099.200
```

Is it somehow possible that the correct `chromedriver` is automatically downloaded?

(when I use the normal `selenium` driver - I just use the following driver-definition, and it works fine with that on several computers)

```
srv=Service()
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)
```

How can i do this also with the undetected chromedriver so it is working on differnt chrome version installations on different computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `undetected-chromedriver`, you have to update the `version_main` arg of `uc.Chrome()` if you don't want to use the latest available driver version to match Chrome. Eg:

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=120)
```

Alternatively, you can use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase with UC Mode, which is basically `undetected-chromedriver` with some improvements, such as automatically getting a version of chromedriver that is compatible with your version of Chrome. Set `uc=True` to activate UC Mode in a SeleniumBase script. Here's an example:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
```

There's some documentation about it here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/2213

Here's a larger script:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
# DO MORE STUFF
driver.quit()
```

For customizing the reconnect time when loading a URL that has bot detection services, you could swap the `get()` line with something like this:

```py
driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax", reconnect_time=5)
```

(The `reconnect_time` is the wait time before chromedriver reconnects with Chrome. Before the time is up, a website cannot detect Selenium, but it also means that Selenium can't yet issue commands to Chrome.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
pip install selenium chromedriver_autoinstaller
```

In code:

```
import chromedriver_autoinstaller as chromedriver
chromedriver.install()
dr = webdriver.Chrome()
```